# Angular httpClient GET request doesn't get to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to send a GET request through Angular-Cli.
Here's my attempt:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
getFirst(){
    this.http.get('localhost:3000/update_first').subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

This arises an error in the console:

```
Http failure response for localhost:3000/update_first: 0 Unknown Error
```

So I checked if the server got the message - it didn't.
I tried the same request with curl (`curl 'localhost:3000/update_first'`) and it worked. So, for some reason it seems angular isn't sending the request.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You're missing the protocol. `localhost:3000/update_first` should be `http://localhost:3000/update_first`, or `https://localhost:3000/update_first`.

Comment: @R.Richards oh. now I'm getting the same error but with a warning: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`. I suppose that is the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problem in your code.

First you are missing the return for your http code

```
return this.http.get('localhost:3000/update_first').subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Secondly I'm supposed that you are making the request to another port so you will have CORS error consider to turn on CORS for you api server too.

Comment: yeah, it seems the CORS request is the problem.